# Incresing Child element width goes outside parent element

Tags: jquery, css

Increasing child element width resulting to go outside parent size. child element only increase right side not left side so that i assign float property to child element. How can i restrict child element width to go outside of parent element.

Is there any CSS trick for this?

Here is my Code.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="tdScreen" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;position:relative;border:3px solid black" class="ui-selectable ui-droppable"><textarea id="input1" rows="1" style="float: left; resize: horizontal; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer; width: 100px; top: 100px; left: 300px;"></textarea></div>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
$('#incresewidth').on({
   keyup: function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {                
           $("#input1").css("width",$('#incresewidth').val());
        }
    }
```

});

**[jsfiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/kwbr35uw/)**

Answer (score 2):

Just add simple check on the value to make sure it's not bigger than the element.

```
var amount = $('#incresewidth').val() > 190 ? 190 : $('#incresewidth').val();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/kwbr35uw/1/

Obviously this isn't ideal as I've specified the max value of the width manually and you want this to be dynamic. but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any CSS trick for this?

*Yes*, if the container with and position of the elements are static or you keep the conditions in your example...
then, the rule you're looking for is [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

```
/*
  if:
    container width: 500px
    container border: 3px
    textarea position left: 300px

  then:
    500 - 3 - 300 = 197
*/

#input1 {
    max-width: 197px
}
```

See updated fiddle: <kbd>https://jsfiddle.net/kwbr35uw/2/</kbd>

Now..
if the dimension, positions or other properties are dynamic, then it's better to go with a `javascript/jQuery` solution..
like the one proposed by @joshStevenson <sup>*(but with dynamic measures of course)*</sup>